# Numpy matrix looking like an array of lists?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to declare a 16x16 numpy matrix:

```
P = np.array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0,1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Outputs:

```
       list([0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       list([0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])],
      dtype=object)
```

Why? I want a pure numpy matrix, not an array of lists...Sure it's something boneheaded I'm doing but for life of me can't figure it out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, lets investigate

```
import numpy as np

P = np.array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0,1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

for i in P:
    print(i.__len__())
```

```
...
16
17 #oh?
16
16
16
```

also note that it gives us a warning:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
```

so there's a length problem!

lets look closer

```
[0,1, 0.3, 0.3, ...]
[0.0, 0.5, 0.5, ...]
```

the lengths are different, that's why you're getting the error

maybe fix with `[0.1, 0.3, 0.3, ...]` to make it `16` x `16`

Comment: Doh! Had a comma where it should have been a ".". Hard to spot visually. Brilliant catch with a loop. thanks, G